# Avoiding repetition of system out print in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm very new to Java, and as such am still grasping the basics. I have a task where we need to develop a program that calculates the population of fish in a pond after a number of generations. While the code does work and produce the desired outcome, I'm wondering if there's a way to not have to write the system out print twice. That is I have two instances where the program will give answer (one for if they choose 'f' and one for if they choose 'v'):

```
    // Integer declaration
    int istartPop, igrowthRate = 0, igen = 0, igenCount, ifinalPop, ideadFish = 0, MAX_FISH = 5000, imaxFish, MIN_PERCENT = -100, iminPercent, MIN_NO = 0, iminNo;
    imaxFish = MAX_FISH;
    iminPercent = MIN_PERCENT;
    iminNo = MIN_NO;

    // Array declaration
    int[] iaGrowthRate = new int[20];

    // Enabling user to enter data
    Scanner inConsole = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Welcome Text
    System.out.println("Welcome to Population Calculator. \n \nThis program will enable you to calculate the number of fish within a pond. \n \nPlease note: max fish in the pond is " + imaxFish + ".\n");

    // Starting population of fish

    // Assumption: starting population must be between 0 and 5000
    do {
    System.out.println("Enter the starting population of fish");
    istartPop = inConsole.nextInt();
        if (istartPop < iminNo || istartPop > imaxFish)
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and 5000.");
    } while(istartPop < iminNo || istartPop > imaxFish);

    // Choice of fixed or variable growth rate.
    // Ensure only f or v can be entered

    System.out.println("Enter F for fixed growth, or V for variable");
    String sOption = inConsole.next();


    // Calculation and path based on 'f' choice.
    // Assumption: growth rate must be greater than or equal to -100% to ensure no negative population.     
    if (sOption.equals("F") || sOption.equals("f")) {
        do {
        System.out.println("Enter the growth rate percentage");
        igrowthRate = inConsole.nextInt();
        if(igrowthRate < iminPercent)
            System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
        } while (igrowthRate < iminPercent);

    // Assumption: number of generations must be greater than or equal to 0.
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of generations");
        igen = inConsole.nextInt();
        if (igen < iminNo)
            System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0.");
    } while (igen < iminNo);


        // Calculation loop
    ifinalPop = istartPop;

    for(igenCount = 0; igenCount < igen; igenCount++) {

        ifinalPop += ifinalPop * (int)igrowthRate/100;
        }
    ideadFish = ifinalPop - imaxFish;
        if(ifinalPop > imaxFish) {
            // Output when population is less than or equal to 5000.
            System.out.println ("If you have a starting population of " + istartPop + " and a growth of " + igrowthRate + "%, you will have a final population of " + ifinalPop + " specimens after " + igen + " generations.\nThe habitat capacity of " + imaxFish + " has been reached; " + ideadFish + " fish have died.");
    }
        // Output when population is greater than 5000.
        else {
            System.out.println ("If you have a starting population of " + istartPop + " and a growth of " + igrowthRate + "%, you will have a final population of " + ifinalPop + " specimens after " + igen + " generations.");
        }
    }



        // Calculation and path based on 'v' choice
        else if (sOption.equals("V") || sOption.equals("v")) {

            // Assumption: growth rate must be greater than or equal to -100% to ensure no negative population.

            // Enter growth rate for 1st generation.
            do {
            System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation one:");
            iaGrowthRate[0] = inConsole.nextInt();

            if (iaGrowthRate[0] < iminPercent)
                System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100% \n");
            } while(iaGrowthRate[0] < iminPercent);

            // Enter growth rate for 2nd generation.
            do {
            System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation two:");
            iaGrowthRate[1] = inConsole.nextInt();

            if (iaGrowthRate[1] < iminPercent)
                System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
            } while(iaGrowthRate[1] < iminPercent);

            // Enter growth rate for 3rd generation.
            do {
            System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation three:");
            iaGrowthRate[2] = inConsole.nextInt();

            if (iaGrowthRate[2] < iminPercent)
                System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
            } while(iaGrowthRate[2] < iminPercent);

            // Enter growth rate for 4th generation.
            do {
            System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation four:");
            iaGrowthRate[3] = inConsole.nextInt();

            if (iaGrowthRate[3] < iminPercent)
                System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
            } while(iaGrowthRate[3] < iminPercent);

            // Enter growth rate for 5th generation.
            do {
            System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation five:");
            iaGrowthRate[4] = inConsole.nextInt();

            if (iaGrowthRate[4] < iminPercent)
                System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
            } while(iaGrowthRate[4] < iminPercent);

            // Enter growth rate for 6th generation.
            do {
            System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation six:");
            iaGrowthRate[5] = inConsole.nextInt();

            if (iaGrowthRate[5] < iminPercent)
                System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
            } while(iaGrowthRate[5] < iminPercent);

            // Enter growth rate for 7th generation.
            do {
            System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation seven:");
            iaGrowthRate[6] = inConsole.nextInt();

            if (iaGrowthRate[6] < iminPercent)
                System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
            } while(iaGrowthRate[6] < iminPercent);

            // Enter growth rate for 8th generation.
            do {
            System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation eight:");
            iaGrowthRate[7] = inConsole.nextInt();

            if (iaGrowthRate[7] < iminPercent)
                System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
            } while(iaGrowthRate[7] < iminPercent);

            // Enter growth rate for 9th generation.
            do {
            System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation nine:");
            iaGrowthRate[8] = inConsole.nextInt();

            if (iaGrowthRate[8] < iminPercent)
                System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
            } while(iaGrowthRate[8] < iminPercent);

            // Enter growth rate for 10th generation.
            do {
            System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation ten:");
            iaGrowthRate[9] = inConsole.nextInt();

            if (iaGrowthRate[9] < iminPercent)
                System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
            } while(iaGrowthRate[9] < iminPercent);

            int iNumElts = 10; // capacity for 20, but only using 10 elements here

            ifinalPop = istartPop;

            // Body loop
            for (int iI = 0; iI < iNumElts; iI++) {
                ifinalPop +=  ifinalPop * (int)iaGrowthRate[iI]/100;
            }

            ideadFish = ifinalPop - imaxFish;

            if(ifinalPop > imaxFish) {
                // Output when population is less than or equal to 5000.
                System.out.println ("If you have a starting population of " + istartPop + " and a growth of " + igrowthRate + "%, you will have a final population of " + ifinalPop + " specimens after " + igen + " generations.\nThe habitat capacity of " + imaxFish + " has been reached; " + ideadFish + " fish have died.");
            }
            // Output when population is greater than 5000.
            else {
                System.out.println ("If you have a starting population of " + istartPop + " and a growth of " + igrowthRate + "%, you will have a final population of " + ifinalPop + " specimens after " + igen + " generations.");
            }
        }
}
```

Also, is it possible to validate "please enter f or v" to only allow those characters. When I try and do a do while statement like I do with others it gives an error that the string 'sOption' needs to be re-initialised for all other instances of it. Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Only show the necessary part of your code please.. Your code is too long.

Comment: you should really use a for-loop when getting the growth rates for each generation instead of copy pasting the same code with slight variations over and over again

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make a Method

```
private void print(String message){
   System.out.println(message);
}
```

And call this method instead of the print statements with the message you want to print for example

```
print("Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0.");
```

Obviously, there's no way around actually printing it to print.

About the validating, you could use the `matches()` Method of the String class like this to check if there's only an f or a v inside the String

```
stringToValidate.matches("(f|v)");
```

Answer (score 0):

To not write more than once a specific `println()` statement, extract it into a method and invoke it from where you need it.
For example :

```
System.out.println("Enter the growth rate percentage");
```

could be extracted into

```
void printEnterGrowthRate(){
   System.out.println("Enter the growth rate percentage");
}
```

And you could so invoke the method :

```
printEnterGrowthRate();
```

It is a first step to remove duplication but you can go much further.

Look at these `do` statements.

This :

```
do {
  System.out.println("Enter the growth rate percentage");
  igrowthRate = inConsole.nextInt();
  if(igrowthRate < iminPercent)
    System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
} while (igrowthRate < iminPercent);
```

and this one :

```
do {
  System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation one:");
  iaGrowthRate[0] = inConsole.nextInt();
  if (iaGrowthRate[0] < iminPercent)
    System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100% \n");
} while(iaGrowthRate[0] < iminPercent);
```

and this other :

```
do {
  System.out.println("Enter the growth rate for generation two:");
  iaGrowthRate[1] = inConsole.nextInt();
  if (iaGrowthRate[1] < iminPercent)
    System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
} while(iaGrowthRate[1] < iminPercent);
```

and so for... (you have 11 like that!)

Almost everything is duplicated.

You should introduce a method that returns an `int` and invoke it at each time you need to take the input for the growth rate.  Then assign the `int` to `igrowthRate`  or `iaGrowthRate[]` according to the case.

```
public int getInputForGrowthRate(String msg, Scanner inConsole){

    do {
       System.out.println(msg);
       int growthRate = inConsole.nextInt();        
       if (growthRate  < MIN_PERCENT)
        System.out.println("Please enter a growth rate larger than or equal to -100%");
    } while(growthRate < MIN_PERCENT);

    return growthRate;
}
```

You can replace your 11 sets of duplicate statements to take the input by that :

```
if (sOption.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {
    int igrowthRate = getInputForGrowthRate("Enter the growth rate percentage", inConsole);
    ...
}

else if (sOption.equalsIgnoreCase("v")) {

    String  commonMsgPartForMultipleInput = "Enter the growth rate for generation : ";

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
      iaGrowthRate[i] = getInputForGrowthRate(commonMsgPartForMultipleInput + i, inConsole);
    }
   ...
}
```